# sed replace line by escaping special chars

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace lines using sed, and usually this works fine, but I am now encountering a string which does not seem to play ball with sed :(

file: test.py

```
$ cat test.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~/.teststring/")
```

I replace this line using:

```
sed -i '/BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~/.paddleocr/")/c\BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("/tmp/.teststring/")' test.py
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown command: `.'
```

Not sure what is causing this. I tried escaping the `.` using `\.` but this does not help either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first `"` should be a `'`

Also, you need to escape the `\` which aren't part of the sed syntax e.g.:

```
sed -i '/BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~\/.paddleocr\/")/c\\BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("\/tmp\/.teststring/")' test.py
```

Comment: yea sorry, typo (fixed in question now), but does not solve the problem

Comment: Strangely you accepted the answer that does not solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/'`, here is my proposed modified command:

```
sed -i 's#\(BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("\)~/.teststring/\(")\)#\1/tmp.teststring/\2#' test.py.NEW
```

- uses the `'s///'` command.
- in `s///`, the `/` character can be replaced by another one, to avoid confusion.  Like in this particular case, you process files and paths, so I like to use `#` instead of `/` for the `s///` separator.   Hence `s###`.

---

PATTERN: `\(BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("\)~/.teststring/\(")\)`.  It is divided in 3 sections:

- 1)  `\(BASE_DIR = os.path.expanduser("\)`.  This part does not change so I enclosed it in `\(\)` to reuse it later.  Parenthesis that are not part of the pattern must be "backslashed".
- 2) `~/.teststring/`.  This part will change, it is the part of the line that you want matched from the original file.
- 3) `\(")\)`: closing double-quote and parenthesis, this does not change.  Enclosed in `\(\)` to reuse it later.

---

REPLACEMENT: `\1\/tmp.teststring/\2`.

- i) `\1` is the first part I "saved" for later reuse in no1) above.
- ii) `/tmp.teststring/` the new text to replace the text from no2) above.
- iii) `\2` is the second part I "saved" for later reuse in no3) above.

---

One detail I could not understand, your test.py file uses path `"~/.teststring/"`, yet you tried to match it with `"~/.paddleocr/"`.  I guess that was a mistake?